# Can I access more than one table via the same DataContext object simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, datacontext

Suppose I have a `DataContext` object and access two tables at the same time:

```
using( var context = new DataContext( connectionString ) ) {
     foreach( firstTableEntry in context.GetTable<FirstTable>() ) {
         switch( firstTableEntry.Type ) {
         case RequiresSecondTableAccess:
         {
             var secondTable = context.GetTable<SecondTable>();
             var items = secondTable.Where( item => item.Id = firstTableEntry.SecondId );
             foreach( var item in items ) {
                handleItem( item );
             }
         }
         default:
           // not accessing the second table
     }
}
```

Note that I don't stop using the first query results while making queries to the other table and use the same `DataContext` object all the time.

Is such usage legal? Should I expect any problems with this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only work if you have support for [Multiple Active Recordsets (MARS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your database engine. If not, you will generate an exception. Otherwise, you can definitely do this.

If you do not have MARS support, you will need to use `.AsEnumerable` to download all records from the database at one time and convert to an in-memory enumerable.

Here's [another great resource](http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/09/understanding-sql-azure-federations-no-mars-support-and-entity-framework/) on what in Entity Framework uses MARS and what you can't do if you don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

AS commented by David.    I would add to his info...
See WEB.CONFIG as follows, MARS=True in connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ContextNameXYZ" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```